# Does removefromsuperview remove subviews?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

If I have nested subviews, will all subviews get disposed if i call removefromsuperview?

Pseudocode:

```
UIView *viewA = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0 , 0, 100, 100)];
[self.view addSubview:viewA];
UIView *viewB = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25 , 25, 50, 50)];
[viewA addSubview:viewB];
UIButton *buttonC = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[viewB addSubview:buttonC];
```

And then buttonC is pressed:

```
[viewA removeFromSuperView];
```

All views are removed from the screen, but are they removed properly?
Do I need to remove all views manually?

Comment: Disposed in what sense? If you call `removeFromSuperview` on a view, it will only remove the view from its superview, it won't remove the its subviews from it. Of course, even the former can cause the **deallocation** of all the views if their only reference count was held by the superview.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All views will be removed. If you maintain a `strong` reference to `viewA` then all of the views will still be there and can be added again later. If you don't, they will all be destroyed.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you have no other references to your views A..C, they will be removed and destroyed

Answer (score 1):

You can check it easy. Create subclass of uiview, overide it dealloc method and set brakepoint there. Than create instance of this class and add it to your view as subview. 
When you`ll call removeFromSuperview in your view brakepoint will be activated.

That`s it.